# Writing multiple values in csv row instead of going next line

Tags: python, api, loops, csv

I am trying to take sensor data from online api to a csv file using csv library. Whenever I am trying that i am getting multiple values appended in a single row that is increasing so on...

```
['22.00'] ['71.00'] ['0.00']
['22.00', '22.00'] ['71.00', '71.00'] ['0.00', '0.00']
['22.00', '22.00','22.00'] ['71.00', '71.00','71.00'] ['0.00','0.00', '0.00']
```

this is the output i get. 
Here is my code:

```
while True:
    data_temp = requests.get(temp_url).json()
    data_hum = requests.get(hum_url).json()
    data_flame = requests.get(flame_url).json()
    feilds_temp = data_temp['feeds']
    feilds_hum = data_hum['feeds']
    feilds_flame = data_flame['feeds']
    with open('testdata.csv','a') as csv_file:
        for x in feilds_temp:
            temp.append(x['field1'])
        for y in feilds_hum:
            humid.append(y['field2'])
        for z in feilds_flame:
            flame.append(z['field3'])
        csv_write = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames= fieldnames)
        data = {
            "temperature": temp,
            "humidity": humid,
            "flame": flame
        }
        csv_write.writerow(data)
        print(temp, humid, flame)
    time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: try replacing "csv.writerow(data)" with "csv.writerows(data)"

Comment: If that doesn't work, try csv_write.writerow([data]) - that particular CSV writer lies things in lists

Comment: Nope, that doesnt work either. I still get the same format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not clearing the lists each time through the loop, so you're appending to the previous readings.

Use list comprehensions to create the lists fresh each time, instead of appending.

```
while True:
    data_temp = requests.get(temp_url).json()
    data_hum = requests.get(hum_url).json()
    data_flame = requests.get(flame_url).json()
    feilds_temp = data_temp['feeds']
    feilds_hum = data_hum['feeds']
    feilds_flame = data_flame['feeds']
    with open('testdata.csv','a') as csv_file:
        temp = [x['field1'] for x in feilds_temp]
        hum = [x['field2'] for x in feilds_hum]
        flame = [x['field3'] for x in feilds_flame]
        csv_write = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames= fieldnames)
        data = {
            "temperature": temp,
            "humidity": humid,
            "flame": flame
        }
        csv_write.writerow(data)
        print(temp, humid, flame)
    time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Is there any way to convert that data into integer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's no datatypes in CSV files.

Comment: Do you mean get rid of the `.00` in the numbers? `int(float(x['field1']))`. `float()` will parse the number, and `int()` will then discard the fraction.